# Javascript Includes giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is becoming a little strange because I think it's something very simple and for some reason still giving unexpected results.

So basically I have an input field and I have a table.
The user can type in the input field and search within a specific column of the table.

So a typical cell might have a date, for example "24/03/2020".
Now if the user types in "24" using includes I get false.

This is a sample code:

```
let _t = $('input[data-search="date"]').val(); //gets the user input text
let _c = $(v).find('td[data-query="date"]').html(); //gets the cell data

var _r = (_t.toLowerCase().includes(_c.toLowerCase()))
```

Now when I output the result in the console `console.log(_t, _c, _r)`, I get the following result if the user inputs '24' and there is a cell containing '24/03/2020'

```
24 – "24/03/2020" – false
```

This is very strange! Somebody please help!

Comment: You should you ```var _r = (_c.toLowerCase().includes(_t.toLowerCase()))``` instead of ```var _r = (_t.toLowerCase().includes(_c.toLowerCase()))```;

Comment: N.B. that you are grabbing HTML from the cell. Try `$(v).find('td[data-query="date"]').text().trim();`.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed why? you just reversed (or i am not seeing something).. It worked thanks btw you can post it as answer for upvote but please explain in reverse it works and the other way round does not.

Comment: @JaredSmith tried that also.. same result

Comment: @Combinu Because '24' is included in '24/03/2020', but the whole value '24/03/2020' is not included in '24'.

Comment: Oh no.. thats a rookie mistake.. :/ you are absolutely right!

Comment: ```includes``` search a substring inside a string.

Comment: you are absolutely right. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Combinu lol that's why you're supposed to give your variables more descriptive names.

Comment: @JaredSmith that is also true... and maybe thats why you should not work for more then 8 hours straight :')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includes` searches for a **substring** inside a of a **string**. So you have to search `24` inside `24/03/2020`, not `24/03/2020` inside `24`.

So just use this line of code:

```
var _r = (_c.toLowerCase().includes(_t.toLowerCase()))
```

instead of:

```
var _r = (_t.toLowerCase().includes(_c.toLowerCase()))
```